# Delete and add data to the mysql database with spring hibernate 4 in single transaction

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I want to update entire database in mysql database through my spring application (hibernate 4, spring 1.4.5).
Steps:
1. delete entire data from DB
2. update new record
3. rollback if 1 or 2 fails

How do I achieve with `@Transactional`? 
I have used `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional` and `propagation = MANDATORY`.
But I can see the table get deleted while it is still in the same `Transactional` Method.

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
private void testMtd(List<Data> data){
  repository.deleteAll();
  repository.save(data);
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Annotating the Application started class (main class) with `@EnableTransactionManagement` will work.